# Is it possible to solve an equation look like this?

Tags: functions

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x+t) \cdot g(t)dt=f(x), \forall x \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Any necessary regularity conditions can be assumed to hold.

I was wondering if there exists a generic method to solve an equation like this.

Comment: Do you intend to "solve for $f$", given that this equation holds for _many_ $g$'s? For example, all compactly-supported continuous $g$'s?

Comment: If $h(x)=f(-x)$ this becomes $$h(x)=\int h(x-t)g(t)\,dt=(h*g)(x).$$ where $*$ is the convolution.

Comment: If $g(t)$ is a probability distribution function for random variable $Y,$ then it means finding an $f$ such that $E(f(x+Y))=f(x).$ If $g(x)=g(-x)$ then this equality is true for any linear $f(x)=ax+b.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the ambiguities of the question, there are some possibly-interesting things that can be said.

First, with or without the change of variables (as @ThomasAndrews points out) to rewrite the equation as a convolution equation $h*g=g$, we can certainly view the left-hand side as an integral operator $T=T_g$ (using auxiliary function $g$) applied to $f$, and the equation requires that $f$ be an eigenvector for $T_g$, with eigenvalue $\lambda=1$.

If $T_gf=\lambda_g\cdot f$ is required for *every* $g$ in a sufficiently large class of functions (for example, compactly-supported and smooth, that is, test functions), the condition is (provably) equivalent to requiring that $f$ be an eigenfunction for *translations*, and the associated differential equation is $f'=c\cdot f$. So $f(x)=e^{cx}$ for some constant $c$.

None of these functions is in $L^2$, etc. But the eigenvalues are easy to determine:
$$\int e^{c(x+t)}\,g(t)\;dt \;=\; \Big(\int e^{ct}\,g(t)\;dt\Big)\cdot e^{cx}
$$

Second, with the rewrite to have a convolution equation $f*g=\lambda\cdot f$, if we assume that $f,g$ have Fourier transforms (in various possible senses), then $\widehat{f}\cdot \widehat{g}=\lambda\cdot \widehat{f}$. That is, (assuming both Fourier transforms have pointwise senses), $\widehat{g}(x)=\lambda$ on the support of $\widehat{f}$, is a necessary and sufficient condition.

For this to be possible for a wide range of $g$, it is necessary that the support of $\widehat{f}$ not be the whole line. If $f$ itself was compactly supported (and continuous, for example), then $\widehat{f}$ extends to an entire function, so cannot vanish on any set of positive measure. In that case, $\widehat{g}(x)=\lambda$, and $g$ was $\lambda\cdot \delta$ with Dirac $\delta$.

... and the equation holds for all continuous $f$, for $g=\lambda\cdot\delta$.

EDIT: as in @user3716267's comment/question, it may not be sooo common to understand precisely how being an *eigenfunction* under translation leads to the differential equation. Yes, we know (by the Mean Value Theorem) that translation *invariance* of $f$ gives $f$ constant, so $f'=0 = 0\cdot f$.

In fact, $f(x+y)=\lambda_y\cdot f(x)$ for all $x,y$ implies that
$$
{\partial\over\partial y}\Big|_{y=0} f(x+y) \;=\; {\partial\over \partial y}\Big|_{y=0}(\lambda_y)\cdot f(x)
$$
from which $f'(x)={\partial\over \partial y}\Big|_{y=0}(\lambda_y)\cdot f(x)$. Yes, *some* (of various possible) hypotheses are necessary to make this argument rigorous. A variant of it does just reduce to the Mean Value Theorem version for $f$ translation-invariant, by considering $f(x)e^{-\lambda x}$... But this heuristic is perhaps clearer as a suggestion of what is true.

Comment: It's clear that exponentials are eigenfunctions of translation, but (to me at least) it is not immediately obvious how the differential equation follows from the fact $f$ is an eigenfunction under translation.

Comment: Many thanks! This is a super simplified version of one equation that I am currently working on, and I apologize for its ambiguity. I will try the things you mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: @cxxu96, good. I do find that quite often the real underlying question is about the ambiguity, after all! :)